# SystemC sc_signal_resolved could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu, systemc

I am using SystemC and Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to setup up Eclipse for a small SystemC project. I followed the the provided readme and the following tutorial [here](http://karibe.ch/2014/02/setting-up-systemc-and-eclipse-for-c-hardware-simulation/).

The problem is that `sc_signal_resolved` is not being recognized. I have a syntax error tell me that `sc_signal_resolved` could not be resolved.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
#include <systemc.h>

int sc_main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  sc_signal_resolved zero, one;

// in the rest of the code I will use the zero and one passing them to some gates.
return(0);
 }
```

Why is it not recognized? When for instance `sc_in<sc_logic>` is recognized. I have verified and the file is the `sysc/communication folder`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This builds fine for me with "g++ main.cpp -lsystemc" (which is not eclipse i know but the code is fine). can you post the exact compiler error message(s)?

Comment: The exact compiler error is : Description Resource Path Location Type
Type 'sc_signal_resolved' could not be resolved myprogram.cpp /location/ Semantic Error

Comment: Appears to me as if it can't locate the systemc headers (as far as i can tell with limited information). In eclipse, go to preferences "Preprocessor Include Paths" and ensure the path to the systemc headers is set - something like "blah..blah/systemc/systemc-2.3.1/include".

Comment: thanks again for replying. I did add the include using project properties->c/c++ build->settings->gcc c++ compiler->include. It is recognizing "systemc.h" and for instance "sc_in<sc_logic>" .  I am using eclipse 3.8.1 and I have no preprocessor in preferences. I got preprocess under project propreties c/c++ general. However I can't edit it. Is it better to add it there than to add it in the build settings?

Comment: If you have only included the system root folder then it may not be able to find elements in sub-folders. Try adding this line

Comment: oops! #include <sysc/communication/sc_signal_resolved.h>

Comment: I did and it did work but then I am getting multiple definition of sc_main which a bit confusioning

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild all again. I had the same problem and after rebuilding, it worked out.

Comment: at first even sc_main was not recognized. After rebuild all, I had everything in order except "sc_signal_resolved ". it is still giving me the syntay error